# Opencart: Options didnt added to cart

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

I have some problem. I have options for product in popup. I check some radio button etc. Then i click to done and in jquery i have this:

```
jQuery(".close").click(function() {
jQuery(".fancybox-overlay-fixed").css("display","none");
jQuery("#button-cart").click();     
});
```

Everything is ok. I see notification for success added to cart, but in cart i havent got any options. If i go back and click myselft do add to cart, then i see this options.

Why there is this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Form elements which have :

```
 Display: none
```

Do not get processed - instead put them on the product page with:

```
Visibility: hidden
```

Then have a second set of identical options in your popup - but then use javascript to set the 'checked' state of the original hidden (first) options if someone selects them in your popup.

So basically you need have 2 set of options

1) to be processed

2) to control the first options from the popup